# how to send newsletter email direct to mail inbox of any other mail account

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp

i 'm .net developer. i just have a task to make newsletter application that can send emails to subscribers. here i just want that each mail goes to mail account inbox not in spam. Is there way to make my email have higher priority and they all goes to inbox section.

In short my all emails goes to inbox folder of all subscribers mail address.

I know google have detection algorithms to put email to inbox section or spam section. here my company gives me instruction that all mail goes to inbox folder.

Is there possible with programming to send them.

please help me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short no, since major email server check for reputation of IP from which mail is being sent. That said check for the reputation of your mail server @http://multirbl.valli.org/ or any other, if you find that (and you will probably find) that it is black listed forward that report to your higher authority citing that the IP is blacklisted for sending mail.

If the IP is not blacklisted then you must be using spam triggering words in the mail.

Since you have said *In short my all emails goes to inbox folder of all subscribers mail address.* then your IP is not blacklisted and will go to Inbox, irrespective weather they are subscribed or not.